# A simple problem where you can't use Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

In [this video](https://youtu.be/Pujol1yC1_A?t=504) there is an explanation of why CLT is so important in statistics. One of the problems formulated in the video is:

> Suppose salaries at a very large corporation have a mean of 62,000 and
> a standard deviation of 32,000.
> **Problem:** If a single employee is randomly selected, what is the probability their salary exceeds
> 66,000?

Here we can't use CLT and consider our distribution is normal and easily calculate the probability. Now my question is how can we solve this problem then? (Imagine that a not-normal distribution of salaries is given.

Comment: Without any other information about the distribution, you can employ [Chebyshev's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality).

Comment: I agree that we can't use CLT here. Moreover, this question has nothing to even do with the (Lindenberg-Levy) central limit theorem, so I'm not sure why it's included in the video. Brian's answer is really the best you can do without any assumptions.

Comment: Technically if you change the numbers a little bit then this scenario does create a case where you can get a better bound than Chebyshev solely on the grounds that everyone has a nonnegative salary. But yeah, there is not much you can say about this "what is the probability of a $\sigma/8$ event?" without knowing something more about the distribution. The point of bringing this up in the context of CLT is to mention how CLT is inappropriate if you are just looking at small samples.